# Static array initialization with pointer to extern struct element?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I want to statically initialize an array, but some of its element are pointer to extern struct.

I can't declare the struct as constant, as their element are modified elsewhere, neither static as it clash with extern declaration.

Is there a way to solve this in the static array initialization, or i have to initialize it in a function?

EDIT:
looking at your examples after a great launch I just found the error was i was using `PWMD2` instead of `&PWMD2` (where PWMD2 is the external struct).

Obviously the error was

> error: initializer element is not constant

Just to point out what i am doing, the partial of the code (using ChibiOS) is the following:

esc.h

```
extern struct Engine{
    GPIO_TypeDef *gpio;
    uint8_t pin;

    PWMDriver *driver;
    pwmchannel_t channel;
    pwmcnt_t width;
}engines[];
```

esc.c

```
struct Engine engines[] = {
    {GPIOD, 3, &PWMD2, 0, 0},
    {GPIOD, 4, &PWMD2, 1, 0},
    {GPIOD, 6, &PWMD2, 2, 0},
    {GPIOD, 7, &PWMD2, 3, 0},
};
```

Comment: What code you have written and what error you are getting?

Comment: Whenever you get artificial problems like this, it very much sounds like the program design is broken somehow. The real solution to the problem then, is to fix the program design.

Comment: @Lundin can you please explain your comment? What do you mean by "artificial problems" and how the design is broken?

Comment: This: "I want to statically initialize an array, but some of its element are pointer to extern struct" sounds like spaghetti coding with various global variables. Either all your variables are constants, and then it is fine, or they are not, in which case the struct should be set in run-time. If I would guess what the program does based on what you have posted, you have an engine driver, which uses PWM and GPIO. In that case, those resources should probably be passed to the driver in run-time.

Comment: Also, when writing embedded systems it is generally bad practice to rely on pre-initialization of static storage duration variables. You should always initialize them in run-time, manually, before you use the variable. Because there exists nothing but run-time on a true embedded system: you don't want to rely on some copy-down snippet at the start of the program, and you sometimes don't want it at start-up for performance reasons. Most compilers support a non-standard way of omitting the copy-down from .data/.bss, it is usually the default setting even.

Comment: @Lundin the struct and variable comes from an external library, ChibiOS, so i will have to live with them.
I find the above struct self esplicative and easy to edit at compile time, adding, editing or removing some engine; also keeping all on that struct make the code a LOT clear as different configuration (that i'll have to develop) will have #ifdef only on struct initialization, and NOT in the code.
"you don't want to rely on some copy-down snippet" why not? doing so as a lot more change that a bug is discovered at compile time instead of run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborate on your problem, because the following works ok for me and is what you're asking to do as far as I can tell:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "externs.h"

static struct_int_t* initextint[1] = { &extint };

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "extint: %d\n", initextint[0]->value );
    return 0;
}
```

externs.h

```
#ifndef EXTERNS_H
#define EXTERNS_H

typedef struct {
    int value;
    } struct_int_t;

extern struct_int_t extint;

#endif
```

externs.c

```
#include "externs.h"

struct_int_t extint = { 10 };
```

compile:

```
C:\>gcc main.c externs.c
```

run:

```
C:\>a
extint: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for example. What errors are you getting? What compiler and platform are you on? (You could remove `const`s as appropriate -- they're not essential.)

*struct.h*:

```
typedef struct My_struct {
    int n;
} My_struct;

extern const My_struct s1, s2;
```

*struct.c*:

```
#include "struct.h"

const My_struct s1 = { 1 }, s2 = { 2 };
```

*arr.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "struct.h"

static const My_struct *const arr[2] = { &s1, &s2 };

int main(void) {
    printf("arr[0]->n = %d, arr[1]->n = %d\n", arr[0]->n, arr[1]->n);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with e.g.

```
$ gcc arr.c struct.c -o struct_arr
```